# Delivery Program using C# - Change values after switch case statement

Tags: c#

First of all I'm going to explain my program a little!

I've written a mail delivery program which allows the user to start deliveries on packages and save values like the Sender Name and Sender Destination then List Packages then Start Delivery on Packages.

Here I have a public class with the name senderDestination where I save values to from a List.

```
public class senderDestination
    {
        public string senderName { get; set; }
        public string destination { get; set; }

        public string delivered;

        public string pending;

        public string delivering;

        public senderDestination(string status, string pendingStatus, string startingDelivery)
        {
            delivered = status;
            pending = pendingStatus;
            delivering = startingDelivery;
        }
    }
```

Here I have a switch statement and in this switch statement I allow the user to input values such as destination name for delivery and the name of the person who we're sending to:

```
           case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        Clear();

                        bool registeringSenderAndDestination = true;

                        do
                        {
                            senderDestination senderdestination = new senderDestination("Delivered", "Pending Delivery", "Starting Delivery");

                            Write("Sender: ");
                            senderdestination.senderName = ReadLine();

                            Write("Destination: ");
                            senderdestination.destination = ReadLine();

                            Clear();

                            WriteLine($"Sender: {senderdestination.senderName}");
                            WriteLine($"Destination:  {senderdestination.destination}");

                            allSenders.Add(senderdestination);

                                
                        } while (registeringSenderAndDestination);

                        Clear();

                        break;
```

And here in my third switch case statement I allow the user to list all the packages we just saved:

```
          case ConsoleKey.D3:
                        Clear();

                        int id = 1;

                        WriteLine("ID    Destination                        Status");

                        WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");

                        // List packages 
                        foreach (var sender in allSenders)
                        {
                            // write here all the information you want to display.
                            WriteLine($"{id++}     {sender.destination,-14}                     {sender.pending}");
                        }

                        ReadKey(true);

                        Clear();

                        break;
```

And the fourth switch statement is where the user clicks if he wants to start delivery on these packages:

```
         case ConsoleKey.D4:
                        Clear();

                        int ids = 1;

                        WriteLine("Starting delivery on pending packages...");

                        WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");

                        WriteLine("ID    Destination                        Status");

                        WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");

                        foreach (var sender in allSenders)
                        {
                            WriteLine($"{ids++}     {sender.destination,-14}                     {sender.delivering}");
                        }

                        Thread.Sleep(4000);

                        Clear();

                        break;
```

What I want to do is when the user clicks on the fourth switch statement in the menu I want the third switch statement to change from {sender.pending} to {sender.delivered} but I do not know how to do this. Can I even do it? I'm sorry If I had a lot of code in this question, I didn't know how to explain it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that the status of each item to deliver is just one, so you need only one property to define this status, not three. In this context, add an enum with the three possible states and change the senderDestination class removing the three strings and add a Status property to define the current status of an item in your list

```
public enum SenderStatus
{
    delivered = 1,
    pending = 2,
    delivering = 3

}

public class senderDestination
{
    public string senderName { get; set; }
    public string destination { get; set; }
    public SenderStatus Status { get;set;}

    public senderDestination()
    {
        Status = SenderStatus.pending;
    }
}
```

Now you can list the status of each element in the list just printing out the Status property (automatically the WriteLine will convert the enum in the correct string)

```
    WriteLine("ID    Destination                        Status");
    WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");

    // List packages 
    foreach (var sender in allSenders)
    {
        // write here all the information you want to display.
        WriteLine($"{id++}     {sender.destination,-14}, {sender.Status}");
    }
```

Finally when you deliver all your items you can change the Status property to the appropriate value taken from the enum

```
    foreach (var sender in allSenders)
    {
        sender.Status = SenderStatus.delivered
        WriteLine($"{ids++}     {sender.destination,-14}                     {sender.Status}");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! It fixed exactly what I needed :)